# Meta tags colour change

Tags: discussion, tags

I seem to notice that the tags on Meta are a different colour (darker) than before. When did that change?

I actually like it because I can read the tags better.

Answer (score 2):

I personally have not noticed this change.

I you are referring to the [discussion](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion), [bug](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug), [feature-request](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [support](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) tags, these have always been darker than the others, since on meta it is mandatory for each question to fit in one of these categories. Said otherwise, you cannot ask a question on meta that does not have at least one of these 4 tags.

**EDIT:**

since the new design went live, my comment above is partially invalid: non-mandatory tags are now much lighter than the mandatory ones.